# Understanding why do we need wheel Python packages instead of just going with sdist

Tags: python-3.x, python-wheel

I am trying to understand what do we need Python wheel packages for . So far whenever i have to distribute my Python project i just created a source distribution package which basically contained my entire source code.

Then why do we ever need to create a wheel package ? Is it just that when we have C code we need to do it ? If wheel solves all issues when my package has C code then there are some packages that i have come across for example `pscopg2` for which simple pip install does not do .

For that we also need packages like python-dev etc.

Can someone give me a comprehensive basic introduction on what are wheel packages and when should i use them over sdist ?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#rationale

Comment: Yes but if my Python module has only Python code and no C code does it make sense to still create a wheel package

Comment: Yes — to simplify dependency handling, to differentiate Python 2 code from Python 3. I'm sure there're other advantages of wheels.